# Iterate through elements of the same name and return attribute by another attribute value

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq, xattribute

I'm trying to find a specific element with a specific attribute value using LINQ and return another attributes value. If I change the name of the element I'm looking for to something unique and search for it that way it returns the correct value. 
I cannot unfortunately do this live as I have no control over the XML format.
So, how to have LINQ go through each element "row" and return the attribute i am looking for.

EDIT: The error is a null reference

The XML (a sample):

```
  <currentTime>2013-01-31 12:34:49</currentTime>
  <result>
   <rowset name="kills" key="killID" columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID">
    <row killID="28024540" solarSystemID="30000967" killTime="2013-01-25 21:41:00" moonID="0">
     <victim characterID="888493667" characterName="Syrsyrian" corporationID="98152004" corporationName="Eviscerate." allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="20220" shipTypeID="4306" />
     <rowset name="attackers" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName,securityStatus,damageDone,finalBlow,weaponTypeID,shipTypeID">
      <row characterID="1062593035" characterName="cal dasiri" corporationID="310281086" corporationName="Un4seen Development" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="5.00586641950613" damageDone="2286" finalBlow="1" weaponTypeID="2629" shipTypeID="24698" />
      <row characterID="0" characterName="" corporationID="98074388" corporationName="The New Lunar Republic" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0" damageDone="9620" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="0" shipTypeID="17404" />
      <row characterID="584494552" characterName="Diesel24" corporationID="753753190" corporationName="Space-Bar" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="3.5" damageDone="2322" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="24702" shipTypeID="24702" />
      <row characterID="90905050" characterName="Thomas Shaefer" corporationID="187930037" corporationName="The Partisan Brigade" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="4.1" damageDone="1940" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="27315" shipTypeID="16227" />
      <row characterID="624484955" characterName="Full Penetration" corporationID="187930037" corporationName="The Partisan Brigade" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="3.1" damageDone="1788" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="27371" shipTypeID="16227" />
      <row characterID="1695597027" characterName="Algazi" corporationID="187930037" corporationName="The Partisan Brigade" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="1.5" damageDone="1258" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="1818" shipTypeID="24698" />
      <row characterID="92087835" characterName="Yasin Stavrouski" corporationID="310281086" corporationName="Un4seen Development" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.4" damageDone="561" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="8819" shipTypeID="587" />
      <row characterID="581357145" characterName="Nykitah" corporationID="187930037" corporationName="The Partisan Brigade" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="5" damageDone="445" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="24702" shipTypeID="24702" />
      <row characterID="92692957" characterName="Mokey PYD" corporationID="98153124" corporationName="Plots Your Demise" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0" damageDone="0" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="5399" shipTypeID="594" />
      <row characterID="90511370" characterName="Rae'll" corporationID="187930037" corporationName="The Partisan Brigade" allianceID="1566707582" allianceName="Republic Alliance" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.4" damageDone="0" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="527" shipTypeID="670" />
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="items" columns="typeID,flag,qtyDropped,qtyDestroyed,singleton">
      <row typeID="3090" flag="31" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
      <row typeID="31564" flag="94" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
```

And the query:

```
XAttribute two = (from kd1 in loadkillData1.Elements("row")
                  where (string)kd1.Attribute("characterName") == "cal dasiri"
                  select kd1.Attribute("allianceName")).FirstOrDefault();

string derp2 = two.Value;
label10.Content = derp2;
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting when writing questions in the future. It makes a huge difference in terms of readability.

Comment: So what's not working correctly with your current approach?

Comment: are you sure you are enumerating the inner 'row' elements, rather than the single enclosing 'row' element?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought "Elements" would go through all instances of "row" regardless of level?

Comment: No, if you want all instances of row, you should use `loadkillData1.Descendants("row")`

Comment: What is `loadkillData1` variable?

Comment: Perfect JL, that gives me exactly what I was looking for. Will keep that info in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all instances of `row`, use `xd.Descendants()`

```
XAttribute two = (from kd1 in xd.Descendants("row")
                  where (string)kd1.Attribute("characterName") == "cal dasiri"
                  select kd1.Attribute("allianceName")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There is no need to do a type-case conversion in that LINQ query. You can simply do kd1.Attribute("characterName").Value which is the standard get property of the XAttribute and would be the preferred way of handling it.

Comment: @Magnum `kd1.Attribute("characterName").Value` will produce a `NullReferenceException` for `row`s that don't have a `characterName` attribute (and there are several such rows in the example XML).  The string cast does not have this issue.